# How to extract files from Huawei backups to SD card

Tags: backup, huawei, sqlite

I've backed up my Huawei P9 lite to the SD Card using the native backup app provided by Huawei.
It backs up each APK and along side each a sqlite DB file that seems to contain all of the files that makeup the settings of the app.

In this case I want to extract the SQLite database, so it seems that I need to access an SQLite database that's stored inside an SQLite database.

The files seem to be stored as blobs, any idea how I could extract them?